# Make priority queue from dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a dictionary where the key is the node and the value is another dictionary. This dictionary has as keys the parent of the node and the cost to reach that node. For example:

```
nodes = {0: {'cost': 0, 'parent': None}, 1: {'cost': 2, 'parent': 0}, 2: {'cost': 3, 'parent': 0}, 3: {'cost': 6, 'parent': 1}, 4: {'cost': 8, 'parent': 2}}
```

I want to extract each node in order of cost. First ones of less value. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is code below that shows one way to accomplish your goal.

However, depending on your design goal(s), you may want to consider using a different data type other than a dict to store node information. Since the dict won't maintain key-value order, you would have to iterate through the entire dict to make sure you get the lowest cost key.

Consider something like [heapq](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html), which is built on a Python list and would give you methods like `heappush(heap, item)` and `heappop(heap)`

> I want to extract each node in order of cost. First ones of less value. How could I do it?

```
def get_lowest_cost_node(nodes):
    # if there are multiple nodes with the same cost, will return the first one found
    # if nodes is empty, will return None

    lowest_cost = float('inf')  # bigger than any other python number
    lowest_cost_node = None

    for k, v in nodes.iteritems():
        # iteritems() in Python 2.x, items() in Python 3.x
        if v['cost'] < lowest_cost:
            lowest_cost = v['cost']
            lowest_cost_node = k

    return lowest_cost_node
```

e.g.

```
In : nodes = {0: {'cost': 0, 'parent': None}, 1: {'cost': 2, 'parent': 0}, 2: {'cost': 3,
   :  'parent': 0}, 3: {'cost': 6, 'parent': 1}, 4: {'cost': 8, 'parent': 2}}
   : 

In : get_lowest_cost_node(nodes)
Out: 0

In : nodes2 = {0: {'cost': 10, 'parent': None}, 1: {'cost': 2, 'parent': 0}, 2: {'cost': 
...: 3, 'parent': 0}, 3: {'cost': 6, 'parent': 1}, 4: {'cost': 1, 'parent': 2}}
...: 

In : get_lowest_cost_node(nodes2)
Out: 4
```

Comment: _dict won't maintain key-value order_ This is no longer true as of Python 3.6. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/4032503).

Answer (score 1):

From each entry in the dictionary, build a 2-tuple whose first member is the value that you want to use as the sorting key.  In this case that's the `cost` attribute from the entry's internal dictionary.

The second member of the tuple will be the entry's key in the original dictionary.  Putting this key into the tuple will allow you to reference the entry in the original dictionary after the tuples have passed through the priority queue.

Collect these tuples in a list.

You can do all of the above in one statement:

```
tuplist = [ (v['cost'], k) for k, v in nodes.items() ]
```

Then use the `heapq` module to organise the list of tuples as a minheap:

```
import heapq

heapq.heapify(tuplist)
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the minheap.  Presumably you'll want to use `heapq.heappop()` to extract the tuples in ascending order of cost, and then use the key from the extracted tuple to access the corresponding dictionary entry and do something with it.  That would look something like this:

```
while tuplist:
    tup = heapq.heappop(tuplist)
    key = tup[1]
    print key, nodes[key]
```

which produces:

```
0 {'cost': 0, 'parent': None}
1 {'cost': 2, 'parent': 0}
2 {'cost': 3, 'parent': 0}
3 {'cost': 6, 'parent': 1}
4 {'cost': 8, 'parent': 2}
```